# Check for new content and reload view

Tags: 7, views, ajax

Is there a Drupal way to use **AJAX** to check if new content has been created, and then reload the view if there is new content?

I think `Drupal.settings()` or `Drupal.behaviors()` may be where I need to go but am curious if anyone has done this before.

Basically we have a View that is a feed of a bunch of nodes from different content types that sits on a display in our office. We have a cron job that pulls in new content from the different feeds that create the content and creates nodes. When this new content is created, I want the view to update via Ajax.

Thanks :)

Comment: I have never tried it but it sounds interesting. Maybe look at [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) to see if you can fire a refresh on node save.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @sareed, Views Auto Refresh ended up doing what i needed.